# ¿Cómo retornar valores que hay dentro de un subscribe en angular?

Tags: angular

les comento mi problema, lo que pasa es que tengo un servicio que hace una petición http, a continuación muestro el código:

```
  getNameUser(userID:string){
    let path:string = `${this.urlAPI}${this.getUserNameByID}`;
    path = path + "/" + userID;
    return this.http.get(path);
  }
```

Ahora del lado de mi componente la mando a llamar de la siguiente forma:

```
  this.userService.getNameUser(id)
  .subscribe(
    (data:any)=>{          
      return data.name + data.last_name;
    }
  )
```

Lo que no logro hacer es que ese `return data.name + data.last_name;` me de la salida que quiero, hay alguna forma de sacar esos datos del `subscribe`?

Comment: defini una interfaz User al hacer la petición debes declarar los tipos Observable  la respuesta la obtener en un componente que reciba en la ruta el id aca lo tenes bien explicado https://mercyjemosop.medium.com/rest-api-with-angular-e7c2ceaaace1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La salida esta ahí, pero es asíncrona. Quiere decir que no se ejecuta en el orden escrito. El observable proviene de `rxjs` que es un nuevo paradigma de programación asíncrono sumamente util para web.

En general, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
variableDeDatos:string ="cargando datos"

unaFuncion (){
 this.userService.getNameUser(id)
  .subscribe(
    (data:any)=>{          
      this.variableDeDatos = data.name + data.last_name;
    }
  )
}
```

Si esto lo pones en el html asi:

```html
//Primero cargando datos
<span>{{variableDeDatos}}</span>
//Después de recibir datos cambiara la variable
```

Angular tiene un sistema de detección de cambios que permite que esto se logre de manera natural dentro del framework.